# Is this the correct way to use Optional in Java?

Tags: java-8, null, option-type

I have a method that looks something like this

```
public OutputType convert(InputType input) 
{
     if (input == null) {
         return null;
     }
     
     return OutputType.builder().withSomeProperty(input.getSomeProperty()).build();

}
```

Since both the input parameter and return types can possibly be empty, I thought of refactoring the same using Java8 Optional. And below if my attempt at :

```
public Optional<OutputType> convert(Optional<InputType> inputOptional) 
{
     return inputOptional.map((input) -> new OutputType().setSomeProperty(input.getSomeProperty()));

}
```

I have 2 questions on the same :

1. Is this the best way to do this type of conversion from one optional type to another ?
2. I am not very certain as to the advantages of this conversion. In the client code, instead of `null` check, the client still needs to do `optional.isPresent()` ? I am not very convinced what I gained by doing this refactor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions quickly:

1. No. `Optional` is not meant to be used for optional parameters. Your usage as the return type is correct, though
2. `Optional` is a *monad*. You are not supposed to use it imperatively, but in a functional fashion instead

Please check the code below:

```
public Optional<OutputType> convert(InputType input) {

    return input == null ?
           Optional.empty() :
           Optional.of(OutputType.builder()
                   .withSomeProperty(input.getSomeProperty())
                   .build());
}
```

As to how this method should be used, don't stick to `Optional.isPresent` only. Use `Optional` methods as per your needs:

```
InputType someInput = ...;

Optional<OutputType> output = instanceOfYourClass.convert(someInput);

output.ifPresent(o -> System.out.println("This is my output " + o));

// or

output.map(OutputType::getSomeProperty)
      .ifPresent(p -> System.out.println("This is my property " + p));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Why do you suggest we shouldnt use it to model absence of input value ?

Comment: @Pritpal Because you force the caller to wrap the arguments with Optional and because you also have to check for absence or presence of value inside the method, which is the same as checking for nulls

Comment: You can avoid the null check using `return Optional.ofNullable(input).map(o -> OutputType.builder().withSomeProperty(o.getSomeProperty()).build());`

Comment: @LorisSecuro yes, but `Optional` is not meant to be used to chain methods

Comment: @fps In my book in this case it is fine since you are doing it to return it. I pretty much did the same thing you did but without the explicit null check.

Comment: @LorisSecuro I guess you're right. Seems fine to use it like you are suggesting. Anyways, I think the null check is way more expressive and clear. Check this video https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=1665 It's Stuart Marks discussing just this

Comment: Normally, the best way to model optional parameters, is to overload the method, i.e. `OutputType convert(InputType input)` and `OutputType convert()`. But in this specific case, the parameter *is not optional*. The method has no meaningful result when the parameter is absent, neither `null` nor an empty `Optional` serve any purpose (other than postponing the detection of the problem to a later time, perhaps, when the problem’s origin is impossible to trace). The method should not be called when there’s no `InputType` instance. Maybe, *the caller* can use `optional.map(Type::convert)`…